# Что означает ключевое слово super в переопределении метода equals()?

Tags: java, ооп, equals

Есть класс Point, в котором переопределён метод equals, так, что сравниваются координаты x & y. Далее расширяем его до ColorPoint, и уже в нём переопределяем equals так, чтобы помимо, очевидно, координат, сравнивались бы ещё и цвета. Код этого переопределения (из одной лекции) выглядит так:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof ColorPoint)) return false;
    return super.equals(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color;
}
```

Я впервые столкнулся с таким контекстом использования ключевого слова "super". Правильно я понимаю, что на псевдокоде последнюю строчку можно записать так:

```
return this.equalsБазовогоКлассаPoint(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color;
```

И если да, то как бы её можно было переписать, не используя слова super?

```
return ((Point) this).equals(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color; //StackOverflowError
```

Почему, кстати?

Comment: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1187-raznica-mezhdu-kljuchevihmi-slovami-this-i-super-v-java

Comment: Уже читал, и там ни слова об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы правильно понимаете, что это вызов метода из класса, от которого данный унаследован.

Без использования `super` никак не обойтись, если метод называется так же.
У вас может быть ссылка типа `Point` или даже `Object`, которая указывает на экземпляр `ColorPoint`:

```
ColorPoint colorpoint = new ColorPoint(...);
Point point = colorPoint;
Object object = point;
```

Вызов метода всегда происходит в зависимости от типа объекта, у которого он вызывается, а не типа ссылки, которая используется, поэтому все три вызова сделают то же самое:

```
colorpoint.equals(other);
point.equals(other);
object.equals(other);
```

Выражение `this` и `(Color)this` отличается только типом выражения, а ссылка остается на тот же объект. Т.е. разница между ними как между `colorpoint` и `point` из примера выше, только в типе ссылки. И при вызове метода будет использован метод определенный в классе объекта на который реально указывает ссылка (независимо от типа самой ссылки).

С вашим изменением происходит вызов того же метода рекурсивно без конца (до исчерпания доступной памяти для стека).

Comment: Касаемо ошибки. А почему вызов именно того же метода? Ведь я использую привидение типа, т. е. должен, по идее, вызываться метод equals() базового класса.

Comment: Я добавил объяснение. Самое главное что `при вызове метода будет использован метод определенный в классе объекта на который реально указывает ссылка (независимо от типа самой ссылки)`, поэтому привидение роли не играет.